# How does proxyquire handle second level (indirect) requires of proxies modules?

Tags: javascript, mocking, proxyquire

If we have three modules names `A`, `B` and `C` so module `A` requires `B` and `B` requires `C`: what would be the effect of this call?

```
var A = proxyquire('A', {'C': mockedModule})
```

Would module `B` get the mock or the real `C` module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only direct dependencies will be mocked.

But you can nest proxyquire statements, so in your example you could:

```
const A = proxyquire('../A', {
    './B': proxyquire('../B', {
        'C': mockC
    })
});
```

Where the file structure is like

```
root
 |-- A.js
 |-- B.js
 `-- tests
       `-- A.spec.js
```

And import `C` is not local.

Comment: property name 'B': … must be relative to where A is; the 'B' argument of the second proxyquire call must be relative to the file this expression is in